# How to fix pyspark ValueError: Unexpected tuple with StructType

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I was trying a pyspark UDF to compute hourly timestamp between two timestamps along with duration. I created below function for that.

```
def compute_hourly_viewing(start:datetime, end:datetime):
   
    
    hours_list = getHoursList(start,end)
        
    hourViewingMap={}

    l = len(hours_list)
    
    if l==1:
        hourViewingMap[createKeyHoursViewing(hours_list[0])]=(end-start).total_seconds()
        return hourViewingMap
    
    if l>2:
        i =1 
        while i < l-1:
            hourViewingMap[createKeyHoursViewing(hours_list[i])]=3600
            i+=1
    
    
    hourViewingMap[createKeyHoursViewing(hours_list[0])] = 3600 - getSecondsinHour(start)
    hourViewingMap[createKeyHoursViewing(hours_list[l-1])] = getSecondsinHour(end)
    
        
    return (hourViewingMap.items())
```

It is yielding output as expected when I tried as standalone function.

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 22, 13, 29, 40)
d2= datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 22, 16, 31, 23)
compute_hourly_viewing(d1,d2)

Output: dict_items([('2010-01-22:14', 3600), ('2010-01-22:15', 3600), ('2010-01-22:13', 1820), ('2010-01-22:16', 1883)])
```

But when I tried this UDF from pyspark dataframe like below , I am getting error.

```
schema = ArrayType(StructType(
           ([
                StructField('date_hour'     , StringType()   , False),
                StructField('duration'  , IntegerType()    , False)
            ])
        ))
computeHourlyViewingUdf = udf(lambda x,y:compute_hourly_viewing(x,y),schema)

df_step3 = df_step2.withColumn("hour_secondCnt",       explode_outer(computeHourlyViewingUdf(col("customer_program_start_time"),col("customer_program_end_time"))))
```

*An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
'ValueError: Unexpected tuple '2021-11-01:20' with StructType'. Full traceback below:
ValueError: Unexpected tuple '2021-11-01:20' with StructType*

Please advise.

Comment: Getting same error with list as well.

Comment: i'm not able to replicate your error with a sample data. does it work without the `explode`? -- also, why `if l>2:`? shouldn't it be `>=2`?

Comment: Hi, for l>2, it does not need to be in the loop as it will have only start time and end time in 2 diff hours.